# what it means to fail the axiom of comprehension

Tags: set-theory

I am (re)reading Kunen's book on set theory, and I find myself curious to know what it means exactly for a structure to fail the comprehension schema.

In essence, it means every definable sub-collection of a set, is itself a set.

So if my understanding of the schema is correct, failing it would meant "there is a definable sub-collection of a set that is not a set", it sounds so oxymoron.

Also in that regard, are there any simple structures that demonstrate the failure of comprehension ?

Answer (score 1):

If you change "is a set" into "is a set in our universe", maybe it becomes clearer. The meaning is the same, but it's a bit easier to interpret in exotic cases.

The class of (von Neumann) ordinals illustrate this nicely (they fulfill *all* the ZF axioms except comprehension, actually).

So assume our universe is the class of ordinals, and take any non-zero ordinal $\alpha$. Then
$$
\{\beta\in \alpha\mid \beta\neq 0\}
$$
is not in our universe.

Comment: What about a simple structure such as ($\mathbb{N}, <$), I don't quite know how to check if it actually satisfy comprehension or fails comprehension. Which is one of the reason I created this post.

Comment: @some1fromhell If your construction of the naturals follow von Neumann, i.e. $$0 = \varnothing\\1 = \{0\}\\2 = \{1, 0\}\\3 = \{2, 1, 0\}\\\vdots$$ then you can see that any number apart form $0$ contains $0$. So take any number $n<1$. Then$$\{m\in n\mid m\neq 0\}\notin \Bbb N$$ and comprehension fails.